# How can I send image in body of email in YII?

Tags: php, yii2

Here is code of send mail function I want to send image in set body.

```
public function SendMail($id) {
    $message = new YiiMailer('', array());
    $message->setFrom('abc@gmail.com', 'test');
    $message->setTo('pqr@gmail.com');
    $message->setSubject('Test');
    $message->IsHTML(true);

    $message->setBody(??????);

    if ($message->send()) {

  }
 }
```

Give me code for send image in set body in yii.

I dont know how to send image in set body?

Comment: Add the image as a mime attachment

Comment: give me example of mime attachment. and i dnt want to send image in attachment i want  to send image in set body @AkhilThayyil

Comment: use `<img src="...">` in html body.

Answer (score 4):

What about these

```
$message[] = Yii::$app->mailer->compose('downNotify', [
    'image' => Url::to('@app/web/mail/images/logo.png')
])

$message->setBody($message);
```

Or [Refer Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-mailing.html#embedding-images)

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose('embed-email', ['imageFileName' => '/path/to/image.jpg'])
// ...
->send();

<img src="<?= $message->embed($imageFileName); ?>">
```

Or [Refer Here](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/mail/#c12350)

```
$uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'anexo'); $msg->attach($uploadedFile);
```

Or This too

```
$image = Swift_Image::fromPath(dirname(Yii::app()->getBasePath()) . '/images/someimage.jpg');
$cid = $message->embed($image);    
$message->setBody(array('cid' => $cid), 'text/html');
```

So in protected `/views/mail/test.php:`

```
<b>An embedded inline image:</b><br><br>
<img src="<?php echo $cid; ?>" alt="WTF went wrong?" />
```

Or this toooo(**Adding as attachment**)

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('webroot.images.mail', '/path/to/your/images/mail/dir');
```

Comment: 1st option give error ;- Access to undeclared static property: Yii::$app

Comment: 1st option give error ;- Access to undeclared static property: Yii::$app  @Abdulla

Comment: There are 4 more options

Comment: i want to store image in variable n thn replace with string soo other 4 option is not usable

Answer (score 1):

I recently found a way to do this.  My solution required an update of phpMailer to 5.2.x because previous versions use set_magic_quotes_runtime() which is depracated in PHP 5.4 and later.  If you use 5.3 you should not need to update phpMailer.

phpMailer has a way to embed images by putting a placeholder in the body then assigning images to the placeholders.

In your body (has to be html) you add the placeholder like this:

```
<img src="cid:header"/>
```

Then where you are sending the mail you assign the image to the placeholder like this:

```
Yii::app()->mailer->IsHTML(true);
$path = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.views.email');
Yii::app()->mailer->AddEmbeddedImage($path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. "emailHeader.png", "header", "alertHeader.png");
```

In my case the images are in the same view folder as the email template.  AddEmbeddedImage takes 3 parameters:

- path to the image
- cid identifier
- image name as will appear in the email